# ACCESS UPDATE OFF OF QUERY

Tags: sql, ms-access, updates

```
UPDATE dbo_enrollment AS A INNER JOIN Get_New_PCP AS B 
ON A.PartD_ID = B.PartD_ID SET A.Nbr = B.['UpdatePCP'];
```

So Get_New_PCP is a query I run to get all the changed values from the database with the latest import file.

The error I'm getting is that I `Operation must use an updateable query`...

Pretty familiar with SQL, and Access- I may have come across this issue before actually,  is there any way to work around it without making a table out of the query results?
I thought it would act like a view...I tried to research it, but ACCESS UPDATE QUERY in my search just returns a bunch of update query syntax...

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT 
c.MaxLoadDate, 
a.CMS_Status_Update_Date, 
a.Effective_Date, 
a.PBP_Nbr, 
a.Unique_Member_ID AS EnrolleeID, 
a.First_Name+', '+a.Surname AS Enrollee, 
a.Street_Address1, a.Street_Address2, 
a.City, 
a.State, 
a.Zip, 
a.Birth_Date AS DOB, 
"(" & Left(d.[Phone],3) & ")" & Mid(d.[Phone],4,3) & "-" & Mid(d.[Phone],5,4) AS PCP_PhoneNumber, 
a.HIN, 
a.PartD_ID, 
b.[Eff Date], 
b.[PID] AS ['UpdatePCP'], 
a.PCP_Nbr AS ['CurrentPCP'], 
IIf(c.PartD_LIPSL Is Null,'W/o LIS','LIS') AS LISStatus
FROM ((dbo_enrollment AS a INNER JOIN cards_april2014 AS b 
ON a.PartD_ID = b.RecNum) 
LEFT JOIN 
GetMaxDateForLISUpdate AS c ON a.HIN = c.HIN) 
LEFT JOIN [CCAPM2] AS d 
ON a.PCP_Nbr = d.PID
WHERE (((a.PCP_Nbr)<>b.[PID]) And ((a.CMS_Status)='Enrolled'))
DESC;
```

Comment: Can you post Get_New_PCP so that we can see what is happening?

Comment: Also, is the field name in Get_New_PCP that you are referencing really 'UpdatePCP'? It's odd that it has the ticks on it.

Comment: Yes, it is a field name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the GetMaxDateForLISUpdate query joined into Get_New_PCP query is the issue. Queries involving aggregates cannot be updated. Check [here](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;116142&Produc) for options on working around this issue.

Comment: Ahh, I saw it as I was posting it, forgot about that sub-query. Thanks for your keen eye. Your name should been KeenKevenDenen lol